# How do you accelerate atoms/particles?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics

Revision of earlier question.

So I'm in 11th grade, and I'm  writing a theory for my Physics professor and I need help. I need to know how you can make atoms/particles travel faster in the vacuum of space. For example, making light travel a little bit faster than 186,282 miles per second. Nothing that has mass would work so the method has to be weightless.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_accelerator

Comment: You could make sound waves go faster by changing the medium they travel through.

Comment: Tagging this [particle-physics] and ten talking about sound suggests a fairly basic understanding of what "particle physics" means. The link that HDE offers if you are actually interested in particle accelerators (and it will tell you that you use electric fields to accelerate them and magnetic fields to bend and focus them), but if you really are interested in sound then its pointed in entirely the wrong direction.

Comment: You can make charged particles faster by accelerating them in an electric field (see first comment). Sound waves don't really have anything to do with particles moving, but rather with (shock) waves. You can make sound travel faster in denser air, metals, glass, water, ...
Nuclear fusion has nothing at all to do with this. Quite the other way round: in order to reach nuclear fusion, you need to move particles really really fast, for example by heating them up a lot (since that is nothing more than fast random movement). Is that what you were asking about roughly?

Comment: Well in space there's always [Fermi Acceleration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_acceleration), but not sure that this is what you want (given that it's for particles & you seem to be asking about waves).

Comment: Light behaves as a particle and as a wave, so it might help me out a lot.

Comment: *"I'd just like to throw in that I have a relatively high amount of knowledge when it comes to physics and atoms."* Relative to what?

Comment: I was just letting people know that they don't have to use baby terms or put the definition in parentheses after the word. I just took it out though, it didn't seem necessary to get the answer.

Comment: and I meant relative high compared to most people. I don't know about you guys, but where I live well, we don't have the smartest people.

Comment: *For example, making light travel a little bit faster than 186,282 miles per second* You cannot, the speed of light is an invariant **constant**.

Comment: @KyleKanos You say that, but according to Futurama, scientists will increase the speed of light in 2208. So clearly it's possible. :P

Comment: The reason nothing can go faster than light is because an object with mass traveling at the speed of light has infinite mass, so in order to go any faster you would need something with infinite energy. However since photons have no mass, theoretically, it should be possible to speed it up if the right method is used.

Comment: That is not at all the reason. Drop the concept of relativistic mass from your mind, it will do nothing but confuse you. Theoretically, it is not possible to speed up photons.

Comment: Yes, theoretically you can't. But, theories are ideas that haven't been proven yet. It doesn't mean that it's not possible, it just means that we haven't figured out a way to accelerate it yet.

Comment: @DragonSlayer3 Theories are not just ideas that haven't been proven yet. That is the layman usage of the term. In science, a theory is anything that attempts to provide an explanation for observations. Theories are also unprovable. They can be confirmed or disproven, but never proven. Gravity is a theory; quantum mechanics is a theory; heck the existence of photons is just a part of Quantum Field *Theory*. Saying something is theoretical does not devalue the statement. So when I say it's theoretically impossible, I don't mean that it's riddled with uncertainty.

Comment: I wasn't trying to sound rude or arrogant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a windy day, sound travels faster "downwind" than "up wind". The "particle accelerator" is the sun - through the medium of heating the atmosphere and causing wind. If you travel with the same speed as the air, you will see sound travel at its usual speed; but if you are standing still, sound "from upwind" will arrive a little bit faster than sound "from downwind". In fact, the difference is exactly the wind velocity.

You might amuse yourself by figuring out in what way this is similar to the Doppler effect, and how it is different. It's all in the frames of reference...

Incidentally - the sun is powered by nuclear fusion.

Answer (score 0):

Atoms/particles are accelerated with an appropriate force, according to the second Newton "law".